# How Do I Allow Comment Moderation for Other User's Posts?

Tags: comments, moderation, privileges

I want to setup a user account that only has access to moderate comments - for all posts - but doesn't have access to edit any posts.

When I give the user the moderate comments privilege (using an old role manager plugin), it doesn't let them moderate comments on other articles.

Is there a plugin that does this, or something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the answer you want to hear, but I'm afraid that is not possible as a user needs the edit_posts Capability in order to access the moderate_comments capability.

(source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#moderate_comments)

Comment: I can give the user edit_posts as well, but they still can't edit comments from other users. It seems that you can only do it with edit_others_posts.

Comment: I went through the code, and it appears there's no hook to fix this, at least not without a lot of hacking.

Comment: You can use the `load-edit-comments.php` and `load-comment.php`action hook to callback a function that will add the `edit_others_posts` capabilities to the current user so it will allow the edit-comments.php and comment.php to load correctly , and then remove this at capability form the current user at `admin_footer` action hook so this capability is only valid for comment moderation screens.